# How to transfer rows with specific strings from excel to another excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, excel

I need your help grabbing specific rows from excel that matches certain strings and printing the whole rows to another excel sheet so I could edit them. File1.xlsx is where my data is stored, file2.xlsx and file3.xlsx is the excel sheet I want to print to with the matching strings; Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

wb1 = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet1")
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('file2.xlsx')
wb3 = openpyxl.load_workbook('file3.xlsx')
my_file = open("file1.xlsx", "r")

print(wb1)

for row in wb1.iterrows():
     for cell in row:
         if cell.value == 'Wave 01':
             list_to_append = list.iter_rows(wb1)
             for items in list_to_append:
                 wb2.append(items)

for row in wb1.iterrows():
     for cell in row:
         if cell.value == 'Wave 03':
             list_to_append = list.iter_rows(wb1)
             for items in list_to_append:
                 wb3.append(items)
```

For Example,
[Here is the excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQgsh.png)
Excel Sheet: file1.xlsx

```
row0 | Column A |     Column B     |
row1 | -------- | -----------------|
row2 |  Linux   | Wave 01 section A| ...
row3 |  Linux   | Wave 02 section C| ...
row4 |  Linux   | Wave 01 section B| ...
row5 |    AIX   | Wave 03 section C| ...
row6 |    AIX   | Wave 03 section A| ...
```

How would I grab the rows that match Wave 01 and send it to file2.xlsx and vice versa for file3.xlsx.

```
Error Message:
if cell.value == 'Wave 01':
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I expected to see the matched string in different excel sheets, like this: But its not working.

file2.xlsx

```
row0 | Column A |     Column B     |
row1 | -------- | -----------------|
row2 |  Linux   | Wave 01 section A| ...
row3 |  Linux   | Wave 01 section B| ...
```

file3.xlsx

```
row0 | Column A |     Column B     |
row1 | -------- | -----------------|
row2 |    AIX   | Wave 03 section C| ...
row3 |    AIX   | Wave 03 section A| ...
```

Comment: It looks like you are searching exact specific string values when you are looking for a pattern. For example: "Wave 01 section A" does not equal "Wave 01" but your operator '==' is trying to find the exact match. Try 'if "Wave 01" in cell.value' instead. This will check if the 'Wave 01' is in 'Wave 01 section A' rather than Wave 01' is 'Wave 01 section A'

Comment: Hey @meomeow, thanks for your suggestion, but I tried that and its not working. Is my format correct?

Comment: Okay sorry, it looks like your error message points to another issue that I didn't address. The attribute error you are getting is telling you that your 'cell' object doesn't have an attribute called 'value', and so its not even getting to the point of evaluating the condition: cell.value == 'Wave 01'; You'll have to use another method of accessing the cell's value. The message is saying that the object is an integer, and so that is probably just an index to locate that cell.

Comment: I ran a quick test and it looks like it is iterating the pandas index also which causing the attribute error because the index does not have a 'value' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is indicating that the attribute 'value' you are calling from the 'cell' object does not actually exist. In this case because you are iterating through a pandas DataFrame each 'row' is a Series in the format: (index, columns). So when you get to the 'cell' iteration, the first thing it sees is the index, which, as an integer, does not have the attribute 'value' triggering your error message.

In order to resolve this I suggest taking this simpler path to get the outcome you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

wb = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet1")
wb['tgt_file'] = wb['Column B'].apply(lambda x: 'file2' if 'Wave 01' in x else 'file3')
wb[wb.tgt_file == 'file2'].drop(columns=['tgt_file']).to_excel('file2.xlsx')
wb[wb.tgt_file == 'file3'].drop(columns=['tgt_file']).to_excel('file3.xlsx')
```

Instead of iterating through the document, you can create a function that takes your text field as an input and outputs the which file you would like to send the row to. Then once that is complete, you can filter on the new field and use pandas to generate an excel file based on that. For larger documents this will be much more efficient than iterating.

Comment: Hey @meowmeow, sorry I am responding late, I was testing it as well, and it works. Now, I would have to play around with it to separate the waves. So wave 03 in file3 would has (wave 03 section A,B,C. Thank you for your help and your time.